# Encoding a lot of categorical variables

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, embedding

I have 10 million categorical variables (each variable has 3 categories). What is the best way to encode these 10 million variables to train a deep learning model on them? (If I use one hot encoding, then I will end up having 30 million variables. Also, embedding layer with one output makes no sense (it is similar to integer encoding and there is no order between these categories) and embedding layer with two outputs does not make that much difference. Usually, we use embedding layer when number of categories is a lot). Please give me your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat this problem like word embeddings, where you also have a lot of entities (usually 30-50 thousand).

Make a random embedding for each category, of dimension 100-300. Use triplet loss or something like it to train the embeddings. Basically, create a valid pair of embeddings, or a pair of embedding and input. For word vector these are words that co-occur in a context window (they are near each other in a sentence). Then pick some other, unrelated words at random. Train the network so that the valid pair are closer (cosine distance) than the random pairs; there are different loss functions you can try, but basically the closer the valid pair and the further the random pair the lower the loss.

However, I would think about how you have formulated your problem. Do you actually have 10 million categories? Why do you have more labels than there are words in any human language? If you can group them into hierarchies so that you have fewer labels at multiple stages your model will be more effective.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I explained, I have 10 million variables (each variables is a categorical variables with 3 categories). SO, why should I choose random embedding for each category, of dimension 100-300????!!!!

Comment: I understand you say you have 10 million variables, but really? Are you sure you can't break that down some? What are your categories even supposed to represent? Moving on, I say to use a random embedding as an initializer because that's what word vectors do - it allows you to avoid the problems with a one-hot embedding while still representing many items.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already use ordinal encoder ? This would encode the categories but won't increase the number of variables.